# What is the difference of SGDSolver and get_solver method in pycaffe?

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to implement DNN (mnist) on pycaffe.

`pretrained_solver = caffe.SGDSolver('mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt')`

`pretrained_solver = caffe.get_solver('mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt')`

What is the difference between the two lines above?
It seems that I get the same result with either of the lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3033,

> The first (get_solver) allows you to specify the solver type in the
>   prototxt.
>
> The second (SGDSolver) is less reliable because if you specify a
>   different solver type in the prototxt, then it will still use
>   SGDSolver and not tell you that you have a mismatch.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!